# Hide show text fields based on multiple select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show hide text fields depending on a particular combination of select values chosen from two select menus.

I cant seem to get the xpath text field to reveal IF Source = "XML Response body" and Assertion Type = "XML path match"

Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="clearfix">
          <label for="program">Source</label>
          <select id="trigger" name="program" class="x-large">
              <option value="">(select)</option>
              <option value="1">RAW Response</option>
              <option value="2">XML response body</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix">
          <label for="issuer">Assertion Type</label>
          <select id="issuer" class="xlarge switchable" name="issuer">
              <option value="containsString" class="issuer_1">Contains string</option>
              <option value="httpsStatusCode" class="issuer_1">HTTP status code</option>
              <option value="containsString" class="issuer_2">Contains string</option>
              <option value="xpathResponse" class="issuer_2">XML path match</option>
          </select>
      </div>


          <div  id='assertionDescription'>Assertion Description<br/>&nbsp;
          <br/>&nbsp;
              <input type='text' class='text' name='assertionDescription' value size='20' />
              <br/>
          </div>
          <div   id='expectedResult'>Expected Result<br/>&nbsp;
          <br/>&nbsp;
              <input type='text' class='text' name='expectedResult' size='20' />
          <br/>
          </div>
          <div style='display:none;' id='xpath'>Xpath<br/>&nbsp;
          <br/>&nbsp;
              <input type='text' class='text' name='xpath' size='20' />
          <br/>
          </div>
          <div style='display:none;' id='jsonPath'>JSON Path<br/>&nbsp;
          <br/>&nbsp;
              <input type='text' class='text' name='jsonPath' size='20' />
          <br/>
          </div>
  </form>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
$j("#trigger").change(function () {
    if ($j(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        $j(this).data('options', $j('select.switchable option').clone());
    }
    var id = $j(this).val();
    var that = this;
    $j("select.switchable").each(function () {
        var thisname = $j(this).attr('name');
        var theseoptions = $j(that).data('options').filter('.' + thisname + '_' + id);
        $j(this).html(theseoptions);
    });
});
//then fire it off once to display the correct elements
$j('#trigger').trigger('change');
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#issuer').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == 'xpathResponse')
  //.....................^.......
  {
    $("#xpath").show();

  }

   else
  {
    $("#xpath").hide();


  }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: try `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle based on your code,

https://jsfiddle.net/2u38koq8/1/

```
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <form>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="program">Source</label>
            <select id="trigger" name="program" class="x-large">
              <option value="">(select)</option>
              <option value="1">RAW Response</option>
              <option value="2">XML response body</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="issuer">Assertion Type</label>
            <select id="issuer" class="xlarge switchable" name="issuer">
              <option value="containsString" class="issuer_1">Contains string</option>
              <option value="httpsStatusCode" class="issuer_1">HTTP status code</option>
              <option value="containsString" class="issuer_2">Contains string</option>
              <option value="xpathResponse" class="issuer_2">XML path match</option>
            </select>
          </div>


          <div id='assertionDescription'>Assertion Description
            <br/>&nbsp;
            <br/>&nbsp;
            <input type='text' class='text' name='assertionDescription' value size='20' />
            <br/>
          </div>
          <div id='expectedResult'>Expected Result
            <br/>&nbsp;
            <br/>&nbsp;
            <input type='text' class='text' name='expectedResult' size='20' />
            <br/>
          </div>
          <div style='display:none;' id='xpath'>Xpath
            <br/>&nbsp;
            <br/>&nbsp;
            <input type='text' class='text' name='xpath' size='20' />
            <br/>
          </div>
          <div style='display:none;' id='jsonPath'>JSON Path
            <br/>&nbsp;
            <br/>&nbsp;
            <input type='text' class='text' name='jsonPath' size='20' />
            <br/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(document).on('change', 'select#issuer', function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'xpathResponse')
            //.....................^.......
            {

              $("#xpath").show();

            } else {
              $("#xpath").hide();
            }
          });

          $("select#trigger").change(function() {

            if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
              $(this).data('options', $('select.switchable option').clone());
            }
            var id = $(this).val();
            var _this = this;
            $("select.switchable").each(function() {
              var thisname = $(this).attr('name');
              var theseoptions = $(_this).data('options').filter('.' + thisname + '_' + id);

              $(this).html(theseoptions);
            });
          });
          //then fire it off once to display the correct elements
          $('select#trigger').trigger('change');
        });

      </script>
```

Comment: Thanks TechBreak! I can see that working perfectly in fiddle, however when I copy your updated code to my local machine and test in Chrome and Firefox it does not work. Also, the second menu no longer filters either.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @fambo what is the error you see. Attach the screen shot. Nothing exceptional done in code i added. Should work normally.

Comment: @fambo try updated answer. In fiddle we dont import scripts so it works there internally. I have added code that will work in your environment. It has required jquery script imported. I hope it will work and you accept my answer and upvote :)